# Связь между словами "зря" и "зрить"

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Зря — значит "даром", "напрасно". Как я понимаю, это слово родственное со "зрить", то есть, "смотреть". А какая тут смысловая связь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зря
Внешне связь этого наречия со словами зрение, зреть и т. п. очевидна, а вот и объяснение этой связи: когда-то существовало выражение делать на зря, то есть "на глазок, приблизительно". В этом выражении зря выступает в роли существительного, и здесь его родство с глаголом зреть не вызывает сомнений.[Этимологический словарь Крылова](http://enc-dic.com/krylov/Zrja-2480.html)

Зря
диал. самозря "само собой разумеется", с.-в.-р. (Барсов). Из *зьрѧ – прич. наст. вр. от зреть, первонач. "праздно смотря" (Мi. ЕW 402). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Answer (score 1):

А может, здесь мы имеем связь не с глаголом зрить (видеть), а совсем с другим - зорить, разорять? В этом случае смысл очень хорошо подходит. В качестве рабочей версии.

Answer (score 1):

Очень интересно: зря - пустая трата... (в том смысле, что от существительного пошло)

Answer (score 0):

Зря  после Заря,  время, когда солнце уже зашло.  Работать бесполезно и ничего не видно.А еще, явно различимы два понятия, восход и закат солнца(РА). Поэтому два варианта--Зоря, Заря. Заря вечер--отсюда зарево, Зоря-утро, отсюда зорька. Доказательства в словарях.